# Вставить в контейнер html+text

Tags: javascript, html, text

```
var str='Hello World';
var tooltipHtml = '<b>' + str + '</b>';
$('#tooltip').html(tooltipHtml);
```

Результатом в контейнере #tooltip будет слово **Hello World**
Но если

```
var str='<h1>Hello World</h1>';
```

Результатом будет

## Hello World

, а нужно **`<h1>Hello World</h1>`**
Это пример, теги будут разные в разной ситуации, как наполнять некий контейнер( в данном примере tooltip) и html и text одновременно? Может как-то экранировать все теги в str?

Второй вариант который может встречаться это когда

```
var str='Hello World';
var tooltipHtml = '<b>' + str + '<span class="error">Часть недоступна</span></b>';
$('#tooltip').html(tooltipHtml);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
var str='<h1>Hello World</h1>';
var container = $('<b></b>');
container.text(str);
$('#tooltip').html(container);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но есть еще один вариант я его добавил в описание проблемы. Когда наш контейнер помимо просто текста str должен содержать и часть html `<span class="error">Часть недоступна</span>` и эта часть должна отображаться уже как html.

Comment: Решил так                     `$('#tooltip').html(container.append('<span class="error">Часть недоступна</span>'));`